# How can I improve my questions?

Tags: support, questions

I am extremely frustrated with how my questions are being received. I follow the rules as best I know how, but I still lose rep every single time I ask a question. Here is a perfect example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294250/class-objects-declared-to-not-be-members-of-the-class

What's wrong with this question? If there's nothing wrong with this question, why am I losing very hard-earned rep? Please help!

Comment: Related: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1842065)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Did I not do enough research?

Comment: Your question looks like something that can be answered by reading the first 1-2 chapters in an intro to C++ programming text. It goes to the very rudiments of learning the language, and this site does not work well as a substitute for learning the most basic aspects of a language.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My question is what is wrong with question itself, not the code. I have read 14 chapter of a C++ book.

Comment: I understand, but what I mentioned above has relevance to this question here. Your original question does not show the fruits of your efforts to search for what is very basic information on the C++ language.

Comment: The C++ tag is an unforgiving place, where a lack of deep knowledge of the language is seen as a weakness, and weakness is punished severely.  Sometimes gleefully.  I am afraid it will become sentient at some future time.  I weep for our children.

Comment: I think it can be said about any other tag on SO for questions describing a lack of trivial knowledge about the language. C++ is not the only one from my experience ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only see a single question of yours that is downvoted, I presume the others are deleted, so I cannot tell you how to improve them.

Regarding the question you linked, here is what I think could be improved:

> I tried to access variables within a class with a single period
>   between the object name and the variable, then I remembered that the
>   variables were private, so I modified the code to this:

Your question starts pretty much "in medias res". It is not clear how this information is even relevant to your subsequent question.

> I got this error from the compiler:

When showing a compiler error, always mark the line at which the error occurs. Otherwise every reader has to either copy your code and compile it themselves, or parse each line in their head until they find one that could possibly cause this error. Both can be very annoying.

> Why is the compiler saying that t is not a member?

Here is the crux of this question, the previous points are minor compared to this:
The compiler is giving you a pretty clear error message. Why do you think that t is a member of Test?
Or put another way: why do you think `Test::t.rtest` is a valid way to access a private member of t?

Here is where you can **show your research effort**. If you for example write: *"In chapter 2. of the c++ syntax reference at [link xy] it is claimed that this is the correct syntax for accessing private members"*, or *"In [this] related answer on stackoverflow, this syntax is used without problems"*, or anything else that shows how you arrived at the conclusion that your code should work; then a reader can follow your thoughts and tell you where you went wrong.

If this part is missing, some may assume that you did not research this at all, and downvote accordingly, especially when the question appears obvious.

Note that in the process of writing down your research, the solution often becomes apparent by itself; i.e. when checking which part of your c++ syntax reference said that private members can be accessed by `xy::`, you see that this actually referred to static members, or something similar.

That is an intended side-effects. The questions that remain unsolved after this step are usually the interesting ones.

---

One aspect that you did quite well in your question: you provided a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your code is compact and quick to read. So there is that.

I think some of the downvotes you received were caused by the raised attention the question received by being linked from your meta question, and if so, that is a bit of a shame. But don't let that discourage you from asking how to improve your questions.

Comment: This is much more than I hoped for. I'm sure I will come back and review this answer every time I ask a question.